# How can I get SelectedIndexChanged to get companyname instead of companyid into textbox, 2 different tables?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 tables that I want to get data from.  The first table is the Contractor table which has the contractors personal information and the second table  is the Company table which has 2 columns, CompanyName and CompanyID.  Both tables have identical column, CompanyID.

The current code I have has a gridview with a "Select" column, SelectedIndexChanged returns the values from the database to fill textboxes.

What I want to do is get the name of the company as opposed to the companyID filled into the textbox (txtCompany), how can I modify my current code below to do so?

ASPX

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCompany" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:GridView ID="TDetails" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataKeyNames="PersonID" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="TDetails_SelectedIndexChanged" >
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="gray" ForeColor="White" />
        <Columns
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnSelect" runat="server" CommandName="Select" Text="Select" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Last Name">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblLastName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("LastName") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First Name">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblFirstName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("FirstName") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Company" Visible="false">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblCompany" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("CompanyID") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="PersonID" Visible="false">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblPID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("PersonID") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

.CS

```
 protected void TDetails_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtPID.Text = TDetails.DataKeys[TwicDetails.SelectedRow.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
        txtLastName.Text = (TDetails.SelectedRow.FindControl("lblLastName") as Label).Text;
        txtFirstName.Text = (TDetails.SelectedRow.FindControl("lblFirstName") as Label).Text;
        txtCompany.Text = (TDetails.SelectedRow.FindControl("lblCompany") as Label).Text;
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your SQL query to fetch the `CompanyName` as well like how you are fetching the `CompanyId` and bind it to gridview and set the visibility to *false*, finally you can set the value of textbox like how you are doing for other controls:-

SQL Query:-

```
SELECT CompanyId, CompanyName, ....
FROM tblCompany..
```

Aspx:-

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Company" Visible="false">
     <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="lblCompanyName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("CompanyName") %>' />
     </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```